# Nginx permission denied (for default user) on /var/log/nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, permissions, debian, nginx-location

I am installing `nginx` from source via the folllowing command:

```
./configure --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-debug --with-pcre \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    && make \
    && make install
```

The `user` entry in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is commented out:

```
#user  nobody;
```

When trying to start `nginx` via command line just by typing `nginx` I get the following error:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/11/03 14:57:08 [emerg] 17427#0: mkdir() "/usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I assume the second error relates to the process of creating the `.pid` file under `/usr/local/nginx`... (?)

There is no `nginx` user in `/etc/passwd`.

1. As what user the `nginx` process is starting?
2. Do I need to manually change anything regarding permissions / ownership under `/var/log` after installation via source code?

Working on `debian jessie` with `nginx 1.13.6`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I executed command `nginx -t`. I solved using `sudo nginx -t`